# How to implement a template class vector inside an non-template class

Tags: c++, templates, vector

During an exercise with template classes, we need to access a template class data through a non-template class (we chose std::vector *)
I'll first describe the classes:

1. the class that holds the wanted vector- "Form". will hold in the future many pointers( hopefully with the desired vector) to an "order form" fields.
2. "Field"- a template class. holds data of one form field(name/id number etc..)

when tried to build a vector with these 2 lines:
`template<class T>`
`vector<Field<T>*> m_fields;`

we got *Member 'm_fields' declared as a template* error.

is it even possible to create such vector?

thanks guys!

Comment: Assuming that I understood you correctly, you cannot *just* do this. You may have some luck with type erasure though, assuming that there is a common interface between different template instantiations of `Field`s. Is there? How would you like to use the vector and what would you do with `m_fields` elements?

Comment: Unrelated: It's _class template_ not _template class_. Swap those words and it'll become easier to read and also to think about what they actually are, templates, not classes.